# Filter a snippet by filename or extension, like *.spec.ts and *.spec.js?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I want to add a couple of snippets to use when creating javascript/typescript unit tests but I do not find any way to set the global scope of the snippet to `*.spec.ts` or `*.spec.js`

Is this possible? [In the documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets) they say that the scope is bases on the [language identifier](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/identifiers) but I just see a way to add another extensions to each language there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this for snippets.  In your keybindings.json:

```
{
    "key": "shift+alt+2",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",

    "when": "resourceFilename =~ /\\.spec\\.[tj]s$/",

    // with the snippet text directly in the keybinding   

    "args": {
      "snippet": "console.log($1)$0"
    }
},
```

---

or this keybinding:

```
{
  "key": "shift+alt+2",
  "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
  "when": "resourceFilename =~ /\\.spec\\.[tj]s$/",
  "args": {
    "name": "unit tests"
  }
}
```

with this snippet in a snippet file:

```
"unit tests": {
    //  "prefix": "",  // not used here

    "body": [
      "console.log($1)$0",
    ],
```

The key to limiting the scope of the snippet is this `when` clause:

```
"when": "resourceFilename =~ /\\.spec\\.[tj]s$/",
```

which as a regular expression would look for a filename ending with `.spec.ts` or `.spec.js` (note that you need double escapes before the period).  So use the `resourceFileName` and construct a regex that looks at the end of it.

Now your chosen keybinding will work in a `*.spec.ts` or `*.spec.js` file only.

See [a when clause acting as a regular expression, in keybindings documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_keyvalue-when-clause-operator):

> key-value when clause operator
>
> There is a key-value pair operator for `when` clauses. The expression
>   `key =~ value` treats the right hand side as a regular expression to
>   match against the left hand side. For example, to contribute context
>   menu items for all Docker files, one could use:

```
"when": "resourceFilename =~ /docker/"
```

I found this thanks to this issue: [resourceExtname with two dots not working](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/66461)